# Find if two different keys have the same value in 2 arrays PHP

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

My arrays are:

```
Array1
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => Melamine
            [deleted] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [name] => Vinyl
            [deleted] => 0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [name] => Polyu
            [deleted] => 0
        )
)
```

```
Array2
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [productFinish] => 29
            [type] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [productFinish] => 29
            [type] => 4
        )

)
```

So, i would like to return first array if `id` of 1st array matches with `type` of another array. In this case, first 2 indexes of first array must come out in return.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i got it with for loop.

```
 $newTypeFilter = [];
    for($i=0; $i < count($arra1); $i++){
        for($j=0;$j<count($arra2); $j++){
            if($arra1[$i]['id'] == $arra2[$j]['type']){
               $newTypeFilter[] = $arra1[$i];
            }
        }
    }
```

Any other answers will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: If this is not the answer then do not post it as such but edit your question instead

Comment: This also gives the result @MarcinOrlowski

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`array_uintersect`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-uintersect) to get the results you want, supplying a callback function that compares the `id` value in `array1` with the `type` value in `array2`:

```
$result = array_uintersect($array1, $array2, function ($a1, $a2) { 
    return ($a1['id'] ?? $a1['type']) - ($a2['type'] ?? $a2['id']);
});
print_r($result);
```

Note that because the callback is also called with values exclusively from `$array1` or `$array2` (for sorting), we have to allow for that in the comparison expression.

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => Melamine
            [deleted] => 0
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [name] => Vinyl
            [deleted] => 0
        )
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/OluSJ)